# Regex Match splitting in phrases based on Operators AND and OR

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this input and i want to split using regex in the following form:

**Original**

```
procedure-type=(C OR B) AND notice-type=(cn-standard OR can-standard) OR nature=(3 OR 9|Z OR services)
```

**Desired outcome**

```
procedure-type=(C OR B)
notice-type=(cn-standard OR can-standard) 
nature=(3 OR 9|Z OR services)
```

If i use a normal split based on AND, OR it will not work because the procedure-type=(C OR B) will be splitted as well which is something i dont want.

Note: It might also have an assignment without clauses for instance procedure-type=C

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the "`Original`" input string _always_ the same form? Or will its conditions, operators and clauses vary at all?

Comment: Why does your input text have (what I assume is) `OR` represented using both a textual `"OR"` operator and the pipe `|` operator?

Comment: @Dai No this is just a character does not represent an OR operator. To answer the first question, you might also have an assignment without clauses for instance procedure-type=C

Comment: Would you have nested paranthesis? e.g.: `(....(....(...))...)`?

Comment: @JvdV nope i dont think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, as per the comment-section, no nested paranthesis; have a try with:

```
\s+(?:AND|OR)\s+(?=(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*$)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BQ8hxL/1)

- `\s+(?:AND|OR)\s+` - Literally 'AND' or 'OR' with 1+ whitespaces;
- `(?=` - Open positive lookahead;

  - `(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*` - A non-capture group matched 0+ times capturing 0+ characters other than paranthesis followed by open- and closing paranthesis with 0+ non-paranthesis in between;
  - `[^()]*$` - Match 0+ characters other than paranthesis before end-line anchor.